# Detecting screen resize in mac os

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I’ve got an objective C sprite kit game that works fine in a standard window size, however when the game window is resized to full screen, the main character sprite needs to have its y axis changed. In order to implement this, I need to check if the window has been resized in the game loop. how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSWindowDelagate. The NSWindowDelegate protocol has windowWillResize:toSize: and windowWillMove: methods.